# Create google maps polyline from multiple mysql points

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-polyline

I have a mysql table with a series of lat/lng points being written to an xml file and imported to google maps as points.  This seems to be working fine, but rather than simply marking them with a point I'd like to generate a polyline between each of them.  In looking at the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines), I noticed that the example iterates through creating a new latlng object for each line/ set of points.  Is there a way I can dynamically call a series of points to generate multiple lines from my database?  Sorry if this seems like an obvious fix- I'm a bit new to the maps api.  Thanks in advance!

The output XML file I'm using looks something like this:

```
Location name="2012-04-01 12:28:18" lat="42.9523010667" lon="-78.8189444333"/
Location name="2012-04-01 12:28:06" lat="42.95219345" lon="-78.81931905"/
Location name="2012-04-01 12:27:54" lat="42.9522356" lon="-78.8192848667"/..... etc
```

HTML/ Script Calling the XML coords into the map:

```
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.9521, -78.8198), 20);

    GDownloadUrl("gmaps_genxml2.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Location");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("timestamp");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
        var marker = createMarker(point, name);
        map.addOverlay(marker); 
      }
    });
```

Code snippet in question on developers.google doc:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2});

  flightPath.setMap(map);}}}

function createMarker(point, name) {
  var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
  var html = "<b>" + name;
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

I'm currently not showing any errors in the console.  This is how I've attempted to implement the two previous code snippets from the original post, but I'm not getting the map to display any lines/ points.  Might it be the way I'm defining the point variable/ it is not storing the array, but a single point??  I've tried using [] in defining "point" as well- but this didn't work/ didn't show any errors either...

```
function load() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
// Create an instance of Google map
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
// Tell the map where to start
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.9521, -78.8198), 20);

GDownloadUrl("gmaps_genxml2.php", function(data) {
var xml = GXml.parse(data);
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Location");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
var polyline = new GPolyline(point, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);
map.addOverlay(polyline);
}
});
}}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console log?
If so, show them!

Comment: no errors in console- see edited post for details. THanks!

Comment: Can you make an JSFiddle so I can try and debug?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/97KKv/
Thanks again for the responses!
- I haven't used jsfiddle before- and I'm not sure why, but the map does not appear in this (maybe api key issue?)- either way, map works on my server fine, just no lines still...

Comment: I can't get that jsFiddle to work, because gMaps is not loading. Maybe you should update your code to API version 3. This one doesnt need a API key, and 2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Here I was asking the internet, and the kid sitting behind me knew the whole time...

I was setting up the array incorrectly.  To solve the problem:
----create an empty array
----use '.push' to insert into array

```
 function load() {

  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
// Create an instance of Google map
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));

// Tell the map where to start
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.9521, -78.8198), 20);





GDownloadUrl("gmaps_genxml2.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Location");
      var points = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        points.push(new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon"))));
      }
      var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);
        map.addOverlay(polyline);
    });

}}
```